# CloudKit from iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, cloudkit

Trying to fetch some data from CloudKit, and I have some strange problem;
If I run the code through the simulator for iPhone 5 everything works fine, but all other devices get an error fetching data. 
If I connect my iPhone 6 to the computer and run it there, it works fine.
If I test it through TestFlight it doesn't work on iPhone 4s, iPhone 5 or iPhone 6.

```
let cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Employee", predicate: predicate)
publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: {
    results, error in
    if error == nil {
         //some code
    }
    else {
         println(error)
    }})
```

Error:

```
did not find required record type.
```

I have checked all records type, data and so in CloudKit Dashboard, and remember it workes fine in the iPhone 5 simulator (if I add/delete data in CloudKit Dashborad, it reflects in the app).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that you're logged into iCloud on all devices?

Comment: BUT it doesn't work in TestFlight, should I ask a question just for that?

Comment: @EirikMadland TestFlight needs production scheme for CloudKit. I think you have Development.

Comment: If running through TestFlight means running a build distributed thru TestFlight, then that is likely to be a release build rather than a debug build. Maybe by default that looks for a production rather than a development CloudKit container, so you need to enable the production environment in the CK Dashboard. Maybe.

Comment: That did it. Added the records in production and it workes from TestFlight build as well. Thx everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deploy your Development CloudKit Environment to Production one. Check Deployment tab in icloud.developer.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you are logged in through iCloud. Go to Device Settings -> iCloud.

Also take a look at this [article](http://yalantis.com/blog/work-cloudkit/).
And code [example](https://github.com/Yalantis/CloudKit-Demo.Swift).